# performance youtube video in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have to list youtube videos in `UITableView`. I am using `UIWebView` inside `UITableViewCell`.

Because of `UIWebView`, the performance of cell-loading is very bad. So when I scroll through the tableview it is stuttering.

I think this is due to performance intensive rendering of youtube link. If anybody has any idea how to resolve this?

For youtube video I am using this code:

```
<object width=\"125\" height=\"86\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"125\" height=\"86\"></embed></object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://img.youtube.com/vi/YouTube_ID/default.jpg

replace YouTube_ID with your video ID
this will give you the thumbnail!

Comment: but what about playing the video after this has been clicked?

Comment: you cant play youtube video directly on MPMoviePlayer, you need a youtube extractor to extract the url.

Comment: https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView this will help you...you can either use the complete app ,actually the extractor is enough.You can play extracted Url with MpMoviePlayer